# The UDID is always returning zero data from keychain in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I had an application in which I am saving `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]` on keychain like this:

```
NSString *bundleId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];

NSString *strApplicationUUID;



if(![keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]){
        NSString *idfa = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
          NSLog(@"bundleId %@",idfa);
        [keychainItem setObject:idfa forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
        NSLog(@"saving item %@", [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]);
         strApplicationUUID=[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
   }else{
        NSLog(@"saved item is %@", [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]);

    strApplicationUUID=[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
    }

// NSString *strApplicationUUIDstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]
                                                 //encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",strApplicationUUIDstr);
NSLog(@"%@",strApplicationUUID);

return strApplicationUUID;
```

But it is giving me always zero data.its not saving for the first time also ,can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your App may be rejected due to Apple prevent use UDID:-

May it Help you:

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{

 NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

 NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
 if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
 {
    strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
 }

 return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong in taking [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString].i am only taking that